# CORS blocking requests randomly

Tags: .htaccess, http, request, axios, cors

I currently work with an api rest where I pass the controller parameters, version and action via URI. However, when I execute a request with URI with more than 19 characters, it gives this CORS error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-api-host/toll/vehicle/v1/list' from origin 'http://localhost: 3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

In authentication the request works even with URI having more than 19 characters. However, any other request with a different URI that has more than 19 characters gives this same error. I use my application's API and the request works normally.

I'm using axios in Reactjs. The api is already configuring to accept the content-type I am using (application / json) and is also already accepting requests from different sources.

My request code:

```
request(uri, params = {}){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .post('http://my-api-host' + uri, JSON.stringify(params), {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.success) {
                        resolve(response.data);
                    } else {
                        reject(response.data);
                    }
                });
        });
    };
```

**What is strange is that if I print some data in my API, the request returns 200 and I capture that data that I print. And after I do that it works all the requests that were giving this error before, then I print some data again in the api and it works again. Weird is not it?**

Comment: Ask whoever is in charge of your API server …? _We_ can’t possibly kow why it responds with a non-success code in this scenario.

Comment: The Server correctly responds to requests made. Before we used another web project with html and jquery and everything was ok. We also use it via mobile app and we have no problems. However I have this problem when using reactjs in the web project with both axes and fetch.

Comment: Well then go figure out how the requests you are making now, are different from the working ones you made before. It’s either that, or checking on the receiving end. You will have to do some actual debugging here one way or another.

Comment: This is what intrigues me. I've already made requests with the same structure that I used in the previous project (using fetch). I also did the correct apache configuration (allowing cors, requests from different sources and json content). I have already debugged the entry point for requests from my api and everything is ok. I've tried other configs and nothing resolves, I can only execute the requests by returning some data at my api entry point before executing the validations (valid token, action, tool and access level), then after removing this return from random data any request works.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED!**

The problem was that my API accepted requests but was not handling OPTIONS requests correctly and did not respond with code 200.

Solution:

I applied a comparison for when the REQUEST_METHOD is OPTIONS in addition to accepting to respond with code 200.